# error when i integrate my flutter app with firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i run my app and its worked correctly but when i tried to integrate it with firebase it shows an error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
  >   Failed to transform artifact 'play-services-base.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16}.
  >   Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\lenovo.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\4c0b774c09d5393feb013f0dbe753af3\play-services-base-17.0.0\jars\classes.jar.
  >   Cannot parse result path string:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `build.gradle`, do the following:

Change the minSdkVersion from:

```
minSdkVersion 16
```

Into the following:

```
minSdkVersion 21
```